# Incrementação em função JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou com dificuldades para fazer um incremento em uma função javascript.

Tenho uma tabela com a seguinte estrutura:

```html
<table id="products-table">
<tbody>
 <tr>
   <th>Produto</th>
   <th>Código</th>
   <th>Quantidade</th>
   <th>Preço</th>
   <th>Ações</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>
     <button onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button>
   </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
 <tr>
   <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
     <button onclick="AddTableRow()" type="button">Adicionar Produto</button>
   </td>
 </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

A função RemoveTableRow(this) possui os seguintes comandos:

```js
(function($) {
  remove = function(item) {
    var tr = $(item).closest('tr');
    tr.fadeOut(400, function() {
      tr.remove();  
    });
    return false;
  }
})(jQuery);
```

A função AddTableRow() possui o seguinte conteúdo:

```js
var inicio = 1;
var maximo = 5;
(function($) {
if (inicio <= maximo) {
  AddTableRow = function() {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    cols += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    cols += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    cols += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    cols += '<td>';
    cols += '<button onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button>';
    cols += '</td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    $("#products-table").append(newRow);
    return false;
  };
    }
    inicio++;
})(jQuery);
```

Essas duas funções inserem e removem linhas dinâmicas de uma tabela. Eu preciso criar uma condição para que seja permitido inserir apenas 5 linhas e que ao ser excluída uma linha o contador se atualize.

No início da função AddTableRow() eu declarei duas variáveis e fiz um laço mas o valor de "inicio" é sempre 1 e não incrementa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode mudar um pouco a lógica, e ao invés de um contador você conta a quantidade de linhas no momento da inserção, assim você economiza um pouco de código, exemplo:

```js
var maximo = 5;
(function($) {
   AddTableRow = function() {
      var qtd = $("#products-table tbody tr").length;
      //somente insere se a quantidade for menor ou igual a máximo
      if (qtd < maximo) {
         
         var newRow = $("<tr>");
         var cols = "";
         cols += '<td><input class="campo-dinamico" type="text"/></td>';
         cols += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
         cols += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
         cols += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
         cols += '<td>';
         cols += '<button onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button>';
         cols += '</td>';
         newRow.append(cols);
         $("#products-table").append(newRow);
         resetId();
         return false;
       }
   };    
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
  RemoveTableRow = function(item) {
    var tr = $(item).closest('tr');
    tr.fadeOut(400, function() {
      tr.remove();  
      resetId();
    });
    
    return false;
  }
})(jQuery);
//renova os ids dos campos dinâmicos
function resetId(){
    $('.campo-dinamico').each(function(i){
       $(this).attr('id','campo-' + (i + 1)).val('campo-' + (i + 1));
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="products-table" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
   <th>Produto</th>
   <th>Código</th>
   <th>Quantidade</th>
   <th>Preço</th>
   <th>Ações</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
   <td><input type="text" id="campo-1" class="campo-dinamico" value="campo-1"/></td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>
     <button onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button>
   </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
 <tr>
   <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
     <button onclick="AddTableRow()" type="button">Adicionar Produto</button>
   </td>
 </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Para isso você precisa mudar algumas coisas:

1. A estrutura da tabela, coloque o cabeçalho da tabela na `thead`,
   para que possa contar a quantidade exatas de linhas na `tbody`.
2. O `if` que verifica a quantidade de linhas está no lugar errado, ele
   deve ficar dentro da função `AddTableRow`.
3. O nome da função que remove está incorreta, troque `remove` por
   `RemoveTableRow`

Comment: na verdade eu esqueci de mencionar, mas preciso do contador pois utilizo ele para dar nomes aos campos criados, tipo <input id="campo + i" e por aeh vai...

Comment: @FlávioKowalske preciso testar mais tenho quase certeza que terá problema se utilizar o contador para criar o id dos campos, vamos supor que o contador esteja em 4 ou seja `campo-4` o usuário exclui o campo com id 1 `campo-1` seu contador voltará para o 3, assim quando adicionar outro campo vc terá dois campos com id `campo-3`.

Comment: @FlávioKowalske veja minha edição incluindo a função para "resetar" os ids dos campos dinâmicos. OBS: Deixei o campo `value` com o id do campo para melhor visualização e entendimento.

Comment: vi a sua edição e estou aplicando aqui no projeto para ver o resultado.

Comment: @FlávioKowalske ok qualquer dúvida me avise.

Comment: o script rodou certinho, porém, como terei cálculos entre os campos criados como por exemplo: tab1total1 = tab1quantidade1 * tab1valor1; tab1totalN = tab1quantidadeN * tab1valorN eu preciso que os IDs não se renovam, pois o mesmo "N" que passa no id do input será passado como parâmetro na função.

Comment: @FlávioKowalske talvez você nem precise de id nos campos, veja este exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/LLudnhw2/

Answer (score 1):

Flávio, como muitos disseram você precisa colocar a condição dentro da função, mas vejo que está com problemas para gerir conteúdo criado dinamicamente no JavaScript.

Então no seu caso, talvez o VueJS pode vir a ser mais pratico que o jQuery.

segue abaixo um exemplo usando VueJS.:

```js
var model = { 
  novo: {
    produto: "",
    codigo: "",
    quantidade: "",
    preco: "",
  },
  lista: []
};

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#tabela',
  data: model,
  methods: {
    deleteItem: function (item) {
      var index = this.lista.indexOf(item)
      this.lista.splice(index, 1);
    },
    novoItem: function (item) {
      if (this.lista.length == 5) {
        alert("Não é possivel ter mais de 5 produtos");
        return;
      }
      if (!item.produto || !item.codigo || !item.quantidade || !item.preco) {
        alert("Todos os campos são obrigatorios");
        return;
      }
      this.lista.push(item);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<fieldset id="tabela">
  <legend>
    Hello Wolrd
  </legend>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Indice</th>
        <th>Produto</th>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Quantidade</th>
        <th>Preço</th>
        <th>Ações</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item, index) in lista">
        <td>{{index}}</td>
        <td>{{item.produto}}</td>
        <td>{{item.codigo}}</td>
        <td>{{item.quantidade}}</td>
        <td>{{item.preco}}</td>
        <td><button v-on:click="deleteItem(item)">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="text" v-model="novo.produto" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" v-model="novo.codigo" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" v-model="novo.quantidade" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" v-model="novo.preco" /></td>
        <td><button v-on:click="novoItem(novo)">Incluir</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: +Tobias Mesquita obrigado pela sugestão. Não conheço o VueJS que você indicou, como este projeto já está quase finalizado adotei outra solução mas vou usar o VueJS em outro projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria algo como:

```
var inicio = 1, maximo = 5;

function addTableRow(){
   if (inicio <= maximo) {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";
    cols += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    cols += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    cols += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    cols += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
    cols += '<td>';
    cols += '<button onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button>';
    cols += '</td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    $("#products-table").append(newRow);
    inicio++;
   }
}

function removeTableRow(element){
    var tr = $(item).closest('tr');
    tr.fadeOut(400, function() {
     tr.remove();  
    }
    inicio--;
}
```

Comment: a sua solução funcionou quase 100% porém esqueci de mencionar que utilizo o contador "inicio" para dar nome aos campos criados tipo: '<td class="col-md-1"><input type="number" min="1" max="90" step="1" class="form-control" name="tab1quantidade' + inicio + '" id="tab1quantidade' + inicio + '"></td>'. Assim se em dado momento inicio = 5 eu excluir uma linha e adicionar outra terei dois campos chamados tab1quantidade5.

Comment: Tem formas de controlar isso, tu pode: na função de remoção, passar pelas trs de novo e renomear td. Dessa forma, vai mantem a sequencia dos elementos. Ou, ter outra variavel, que só incrementa. e usar essa nova variavel pra dar os nomes dos seus elementos. ok?

Answer (score 0):

Modifiquei apenas onde o contador é aplicado para não fugir do que você pensou:

```js
(function($) {
  RemoveTableRow = function(item) {
    inicio--;
    var tr = $(item).closest('tr');
    tr.fadeOut(400, function() {
      tr.remove();
    });
    return false;
  }
})(jQuery);

var inicio = 1;
var maximo = 5;
(function($) {

  AddTableRow = function() {
    if (inicio < maximo) {
      inicio++;
      var newRow = $("<tr>");
      var cols = "";
      cols += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
      cols += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
      cols += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
      cols += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
      cols += '<td>';
      cols += '<button onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button>';
      cols += '</td>';
      newRow.append(cols);
      $("#products-table").append(newRow);
      return false;
    };
  }

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="products-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Produto</th>
      <th>Código</th>
      <th>Quantidade</th>
      <th>Preço</th>
      <th>Ações</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <button onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
        <button onclick="AddTableRow()" type="button">Adicionar Produto</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Coloquei o incremento dentro do evento click e dentro da condição que verifica o limite de linhas, e decrementando na função que remove a linha.